# How to discover thread protocol enabled end devices from mobile application?

Tags: android, network-protocols

I am working on IOT based protocol ie Thread. I am able to discover Border Router which has both wifi interface and 802.15.4 interface using the jmdns library in android, the same way I want to discover Thread enabled End devices, How can I Discover end nodes from the mobile application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End Node in thread network  communicate over 802.15.4.
In Thread network endnode will talk only with BorderRouter.
So its not possible to discover thread protocol enabled end devices from mobile application.